# If certain Select Option is Selected, change div's css to "Display:None"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change my form inputs based on which "sex" (i.e. mr, mrs, ms.) a user selects. If a user selects "mr", I want to alter the form to tailor the inputs to his sex. To do that, I need some of the questions to disappear.

My JSFiddle is here 
[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndc497r1/1/)

HTML

```
<select name="prefix" id="prefix">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
            <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
            <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
</select> 

<div id="disappear">
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
        if($('#prefix').val("mr")){
            $("#disappear").css("display", "none");
        };
</script>
```

Thanks a bunch guys, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#prefix').on("change", function () {
        if ($(this).val()=="mr") {
            $("#disappear").css("display", "none");
        };
        else{
            $("#disappear").css("display", "block");
        }
    });
})
```

You need to wrap that code in the change event handler

Comment: Okay thank you! How do I make the css reappear if someone were to select mr, but then select ms or mrs?

Comment: Thanks, I used the same "if" statement you gave me except I just but it inside an "else" statement, changed ".val()=="mr" to "val()=="ms","mrs"" and changed "none" to "".

Answer (score 0):

You'll need an event handler as well, something like

```
$('#prefix').on('change', function() {
    $("#disappear").toggle( this.value !== 'mr' );
});
```

Using `toggle` toggles the visibility based on the value.

[**FIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/ndc497r1/4/)

Answer (score 0):

All of the above, here's your [working fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ndc497r1/2/).

```
$('#prefix').on('change', function(){
        if($('#prefix').val("mr")){
            $("#disappear").css("display", "none");
        };
});
```

Comment: It will change the value to `mr` whenever change event fired

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to hide all questions not relating to the selected prefix, then you could try this approach.

Use classes for your `div` wrapper of each question, one main class to tie all of the questions together (i.e. `.question`), and one class for each prefix respective of the values for each selected option (i.e. `.mr` `.ms` `.mrs`).

- If you want a question to be seen using all prefixes, leave out the prefix class for that question.
- If you want a question to be seen under multiple (but not all) prefixes, you can set multiple prefix classes for that question.

Select all of the questions on their main tag, then filter the results based on the known prefix tags. This will exclude all questions that should be seen by all prefixes.

Define a function to hide all questions and show only those with the class matching the selected option.

Run this function when the DOM loads and create an event listener for the select element's change event to run this function.

```js
var questions = $('.question').filter('.mr, .ms, .mrs');
hideAll();
$('#prefix').change(hideAll);

function hideAll() {
    questions.hide();
    questions.filter('.' + this.value).show();
}
```

```css
.question { padding-top: 5px; margin-top: 5px; border-top: 1px solid #ccc; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="prefix">
    Select a prefix:
    <select name="prefix" id="prefix">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="mr">Mr.</option>
        <option value="ms">Ms.</option>
        <option value="mrs">Mrs.</option>
    </select>
</label>
<!-- No prefix class, will be seen by all -->
<div class="question">        Will this question be seen by all?                          </div>
<div class="question mr">     What is a question?<br>                    <sup>Mr.</sup>   </div>
<div class="question ms">     What is a question not?<br>                <sup>Ms.</sup>   </div>
<div class="question mrs">    Why?<br>                                   <sup>Mrs.</sup>  </div>
<!-- Two prefix classes, will be seen by mr and mrs -->
<div class="question mr mrs"> This question occurs for two prefixes?<br> <sup>M/rs.</sup> </div>
```